# Remove partial input auto-complete from datalist input

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, input, datalist

I have a datalist and input like the following:

```html
<input id="1" list="test_list">
<datalist id="test_list">
  <option>2015_02_03</option>
  <option>2015_02_01</option>
  <option>2014_12_11</option>
  <option>2014_12_19</option>
</datalist>
```

When typing into the input, the list removes all options without that start of the string.

e.g. typing 2015 removes all 2014 options from the dropdown.

I would like the full datalist there at all times. is there a way to do this?

I have tried autocomplete=false, but this doesn't work.

If you use chrome you will see a dropdown arrow that keeps all the datalist when pressed however firefox doesn't have this.

Comment: `autocomplete=false` will remove the browser's remembered values of similar forms but it doesn't touch datalist's autocompletion. If set to true (default), Firefox will show both lists separated with a line in the dropdown.

Comment: Yes, I saw this. But can't seem to manipulate the datalist to keep the full list there.